# How to assign a variable referenced by address in GCC inline ASM on ARM

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I want to copy 4 8 bit variables from a memory address to a ARM register to be able to work with **usad8** instruction. So my code is like:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "eor %0, %0, %0;"       

    "eor %%r2, %%r2, %%r2;"
    "ldrd %%r2, %1;"

    "eor %%r4, %%r4, %%r4;"
    "ldrd  %%r4, %2;"

    "usad8 %0, %%r2, %%r4"
    :"=r" (acc)
    :"m" (add_b), "m" (add_s)
    );
```

but it gives me strange results. **add_b** and **add_s** are pointers storing memory addresses. I found out, that the **ldrd** copies only the address to **r2** and **r4**. I compile with gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3 on Raspberry Pi. Any ideas?

EDIT:
This version of the code worked:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "ldr %%r1, [%1];"
    "ldr %%r2, [%2];"

    "usad8 %0, %%r1, %%r2"
    :"=r" (acc)
    :"r" (add_b), "r" (add_s)
    :"r1", "r2"
    );'
```

Thanks everybody for helping!

Comment: You'd better mark `r2` and `r4` as clobbers. And what's the point of all the `eor` instructions?

Comment: `ldrd` loads a 64-bit value into two registers, which is at odds with what you say you want to do. Why not just prepare the register in the C code (shift and or `unsigned char`s into an `unsigned int`), then pass that to the asm?

Comment: [How to pass a long long-typed parameter when calling c function from arm assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609622/how-to-pass-a-long-long-typed-parameter-when-calling-c-function-from-arm-assembl)

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, marking as clobbers is a good idea. I am using **eor** to reset those registers to zero, AFAIK this is the fastest way.

Comment: @Notlikethat I thought that 1 word is 2 bytes, obviously I was wrong. Preparing the variable is a very good workaround, I achieved 2x speedup with this. I wanted to copy the values directly from the memory, because on X86 it worked easily and I thought this will work here as well.

Comment: @Notlikethat It turned out, I was using a custom ABS function, with the built-in it was only a 34% speedup.

Comment: In Intel land, 16 bits is a word and 32 bits is a doubleword, since the 8086 was a 16-bit architecture and everything grew from there. ARM has always been 32-bit, so we have 32-bit words and 16-bit _halfwords_ ;) I think Carl's point is that zeroing the registers before overwriting them is a pointless waste of code - again, no AL/AX/EAX shenanigans from 16-bit origins here, loading into a register always sets the whole thing (halfword/byte loads are zero or sign extended to 32 bits depending on the instruction).